# Why are all my conversions in GA4 marked as "direct"?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, conversions, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

I run a small webapp. The app is hosted on `app.mydomain.com` and my 'main' website is just on `mydomain.com`. On my main website I installed Google Tag Manager and installed/linked a GA4 property. On the subdomain I just directly pasted the tracking code in the `<head>` of the same GA4 property as on my main website as [this article suggests](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/subdomain-tracking-with-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager/). So both the subdomain and the main site use the same tracking code.

The problem is that all my conversions are marked as 'direct'. I know that this can't be true, because 99% of my traffic comes from Google Search and I just started with Google Ads. So I would expect to see all my conversions being marked with `Google search` or `Paid`:

[image]

The `Traffic acquisition` does show multiple traffic sources:

[image]

The only thing I can think of, is that I track my conversions probably a bit different than most people. Once a payment is made, my server sends a request to Google Analytics to generate a conversion event:

```
exports.generateGA4Conversion = async () => {
  const measurement_id = process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID;
  const api_secret = process.env.GA4_API_SECRET;

  fetch(
    `https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: "123",
        events: [
          {
            name: "conversion",
            params: { succes: true },
          },
        ],
      }),
    }
  );
};
```

Could that be the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your custom script is the "culprit". It happens in this section:

```
 headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
```

You are sending a custom set of headers, basically **User Agent** and **Content-Type**. If you want to identify the **Direct** traffic, you need to add the **Referer** header with the relevant information.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you provide an example? The code I used came directly from the Google docs...

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you could try adding after:  *"Content-Type": "application/json",* the following: *"Referer": Document.referrer,*